# Interpolation with boundary conditions

Tags: dynamic, interpolation

I'm working on a sales projection, trying to create some flexibility in handle the forecast using locators.

The toy code is something like this:

```
DynamicModule[{pts={{1,1},{2,1}}}
    ,LocatorPane[
        Dynamic[pts]
       ,Dynamic@Plot[Piecewise[{{InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0,1},Sequence@@pts,{3,5}},x],x<3},{5,x>3}}],{x,0,5},PlotRange->{{0,5},{0,6}}]
    ]
]
```

[image: plot]

Where I can change the locators position in order to change the curve.

**The question is, assuming my plot functions as `f[x]`**

1. How to define `f'[3]=0` to don't get the slop break in `{3,5}`?
2. How to define `f'[0]>0` to don't get a initial down slope?

So I could control the polinomial order to get these conditions met, still using locators.

Maybe using `NDSolve` together with `LinearModelFit`? Or is there a simpler way?

**Update**

The first condition was solved by @kguler and @belisarius. Tks to both.

Some clue for the second?

Comment: For (1) you can use `{3, 5, 0}` instead of `{3,5}`. For (20, changing the first point `{0,1}` to `{0,1,1}` controls the slope at `x=0` but, it seems, patterns like `{0,1,_Positive}` don't work..

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add 0 valued derivatives at {3,5} and a slider for controlling the derivative at 0:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, d},
 Column@{
   Slider[Dynamic[d], {0, 3}],
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
    Dynamic@
     Plot[Piecewise[{{InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, 1, d, 0}, 
           Sequence @@ pts, {3, 5, 0, 0, 0}}, x], x < 3}, {5, x > 3}}], 
         {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 6}}]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

To get a positive derivative at `x=0`, you may also dynamically add more locators like this:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
  Dynamic@Plot[Piecewise[{{InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, 1}, 
      Sequence @@ Sort@pts, {3, 5, 0, 0, 0}}, x], x < 3}, {5, x > 3}}], {x, 0, 5}, 
          PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 6}}],  LocatorAutoCreate -> True]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very interesting and simple!.. I get a even better effect with `{3, 5, 0, 0}` tks +1

Answer (score 2):

Adding values for the first, second, third... derivatives at `x=0` and `x=3`:

```
 DynamicModule[{pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}}}, 
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], Dynamic@Plot[
   Piecewise[{{InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, 1, 0, 1}, 
     Sequence @@ pts, {3, 5, 0, 1}}, x], x < 3}, {5, x > 3}}],
     {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 6}}]]]
```

[image]
[ref/Interpolating Ploynomial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html)

**Update:** Tie the first/second/... derivatives at `x=0` and `x=3` to the locator values; for example:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}}}, 
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],  Dynamic@Plot[
Piecewise[{{InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, 1, 0, Abs@pts[[1, 2]]}, 
     Sequence @@ pts, {3, 5, 0, -Abs[pts[[2, 2]]]}}, x],   x < 3},
   {5, x > 3}}], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 6}}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A possible way by using one curve to get the derivative, then substituting into another one:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, func},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
  Dynamic[
   Plot[{
     Piecewise[{{(func = Interpolation[{
             {{0}, 1},
             {{pts[[1, 1]]}, pts[[1, 2]]},
             {{pts[[2, 1]]}, pts[[2, 2]]},
             {{3}, 5, 0}
             }])[x], x < 3}, {5, x > 3}}],
     Piecewise[{{Interpolation[{
           {{0}, 1, If[# < 0, 0, #] &[func'[0]]},
           {{pts[[1, 1]]}, pts[[1, 2]], func'[pts[[1, 1]]]},
           {{pts[[2, 1]]}, pts[[2, 2]], func'[pts[[2, 1]]]},
           {{3}, 5, 0}
           }][x], x < 3}, {5, x > 3}}]
     }, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 6}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[.5], Red}]
   ]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For real applications, only plot the curve needed:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}}, func},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
  DynamicWrapper[
   Dynamic@Plot[Piecewise[{{Interpolation[{
           {{0}, 1, If[# < 0, 0, #] &[func'[0]]},
           {{pts[[1, 1]]}, pts[[1, 2]], func'[pts[[1, 1]]]},
           {{pts[[2, 1]]}, pts[[2, 2]], func'[pts[[2, 1]]]},
           {{3}, 5, 0}
           }][x], x < 3}, {5, x > 3}}], {x, 0, 5}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 6}} ],
   func = Interpolation[{
      {{0}, 1},
      {{pts[[1, 1]]}, pts[[1, 2]]},
      {{pts[[2, 1]]}, pts[[2, 2]]},
      {{3}, 5, 0}
      }]
   ]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]